# Mockk - spyk mock method only once

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I have `spyk` from `mockk` library:

```
my = spyk(My())
```

later I am mocking one of the method to return something like:

```
every { my.method("someString") } returns something
```

I'm creating this `spyk` in a `@BeforeAll` method and I'm reusing it a few times but, sometimes I need to call real `my.method("someString")` instead of mocked version, but this `every{}` mocked it everywhere.

How to force `my` to call real method in some cases? Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

to call original method, you can use answer infix with lambda. This lambda receives `MockKAnswerScope` as `this` and it contains handy `callOriginal()` method

```
every { my.method("something") } answers { callOriginal() }
```

---

example:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {

    private val my = spyk(My())

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val something = "Something"

        every { my.method("something") } returns something
        // now method will return specific value stated above
        assertEquals(something, my.method("something"))

        every { my.method("something") } answers { callOriginal() }
        // now method will call original code
        assertEquals("My something is FUN!", my.method("something"))
    }
}

class My {
    fun method(item: String): String {
        return "My $item is FUN!"
    }
}
```